# VB.NET web application - Update a data bound Listbox when underlying table / query changes

Tags: sql, vb.net, listbox

I have a page in my web application that contains two listboxes with buttons to move items back & forth between them.  Each listbox is bound to a SQL query, the results of which change as the selected items are added or removed from the corresponding lists.  This all works fine, except I cannot get the list boxes to update their contents on the fly, however if I refresh the web page, the contents update correctly.

Basically the user selects items in LeftListbox and clicks the Add button which calls code to loop through the LeftListbox and for each selected item adds a new record to a table (Score).  The RightListbox should then update to show that the items have been added to the table.

Here is a snippet of code from the Click event of the Add button:

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To (LeftListbox.Items.Count() - 1)

    If LeftListbox.Items(i).Selected Then

        Try
            DbUtils.StartTransaction()

            Dim rec As ScoreRecord = New ScoreRecord
            rec.Player_ID = CInt(Me.LeftListbox.Items(i).Value)
            rec.Save()

            DbUtils.CommitTransaction()

        Catch ex As Exception
            DbUtils.RollBackTransaction()
            Me.Page.ErrorOnPage = True

        Finally
            DbUtils.EndTransaction()

        End Try
    End If

Next i

'** Here is where I want to refresh the list **
```

I've searched quite a bit for a solution, but I can't find anything that works so any help would be much appreciated.

Andrew

Comment: lookup AJAX or jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the same method (or code) used to populate the "right listbox" in the first place.  The right ListBox's DataSource will be the same as it was prior to this code snipped being ran, so it must be updated since the underlying data has changed.

Comment: Thanks for stating the obvious. (no sarcasm intended) :^)
I'd got so focused on looking for a 'simple' solution that I overlooked one I already had.  I'm fairly new to .NET programming & I thought there must be a method similar to the VBA Control.ReQuery command that would do the same job.  I have a function that initially populates the listboxes and calling it to refresh them works nicely as well.

Andrew